# Jaspersoft Studio does not display well a report template created in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jaspersoft-studio

I created a report template using *iReport*. 
I want to show that report template in *Jaspersoft Studio* too.
The problem is printWhenExpression tag does not work properly in *Jaspersoft Studio* so nothing is filtered.

Is that normal?

Comment: You should add info about version of both applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
I choose the language Groovy in iReports and Java in Jaspersoft Studio. It causes not to work "==" and "!=" operators in java which work fine Groove. I changed the language to Java and replaced those operators with equals() or new Boolean(!$F{field_name}.equals(Object)).